# How to use MapBox maps with Mapquest route service?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapquest

I have a KML file with custom bicycling paths imported into MapBox map using TileMill. This map does not have any roads, highway, walking paths, other than these bicycling paths that I specified. Since MapBox does not have a routing service would it be possible to use Map Quest routing service with my custom MapBox map with the special bicycling paths I specified? or is there some other technology to allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

While you can [set the routeType to bicycle](http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/#advancedoptions) in the Directions Web Service, it does not take any custom data for the route.  It takes the locations, not the route links, in the request.